# Impressions/Clicks counting design for heavy load

Tags: database, nosql

We have an affiliate system which counts millions of banner Impressions/Clicks per day.
Currently it writes to SQL every Impression/Click that occurs in real time on each request.

Web application serves these requests.

**We are facing two problems:**

1. If we have a lot of concurrent requests per second, the SQL is
   starting to work very hard to insert the Impressons/Clicks data and
   as a result lead to problem #2.
2. If SQL is slow at the moment, the requests are being accumulated and
   are waiting in the queue on web server. As a result we have a
   slowness on a web application and requests are not being processed.

**Design we thought of in high level:**

> We are now considering changing the design by taking out the writing to SQL logic out of web application (write it to some local storage instead) and making a stand alone service which will read from local storage and eventually write the aggregated Impressions/Clicks data (not in real time) to SQL in background.

**Our constraints:**

- 10 web servers (load balanced)
- 1 SQL server

What do you think of suggested design?
Would you use NoSQL as local storage for each web server?
Suggest your alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that your front-end code is synchronusly blocking while waiting for the back-end code to update the database.

Decouple front-end and back-end, e.g. by putting a queue inbetween where the front-end can write to the queue with low latency and high throughput. The back-end then can take its time to process the queued data into their destinations.

It may or may not be necessary to make the queue restartable (i.e. not losing data after a crash). Depending on this, you have various options:

- In-memory queue, speedy but not crash-proof.
- Database queue, makes sense if writing the raw request data to a simple data structure is faster than writing the final data into its target data structures.
- Renundant queues, to cover for crashes.

Comment: Problem with queue is that we have to validate each and every impressions for uniqueness. That means that we will have to take all the queue data for specific day into memory and filter out non unique impressions. Why not using in this case a NoSQL DB and apply to this data a Map Reduce algorithm?

Comment: The primary idea is to do the unique impressions filtering asynchronously at a later stage in order to let your workers go back to work quickly. The actual design of the filter is secondary.

Answer (score 0):

I'm with Bernd, but I'm not sure about using a queue specifically.

All you need is something asynchronous that you can call; that way the act of logging the impression is pretty much redundant.

Comment: Well, don't take the term "queue" too literally. We don't know enough about the actual environment to recommend concrete solutions IMHO.

Comment: True!  I guess the good thing about a 'proper' queue is that it would be a good way of preserving the data as well as introducing asynchronous behavior, since clicks/imprints = money/contractuals.